# "Too small initial heap" when running Java

Tags: linux, java

I'm trying to run the Java program `trimmomatic.jar` and I'm getting an error related to "initial heap". Any idea what this is?

```
java -Xmx500 -jar trimmomatic.jar PE -threads 20 -phred33 ../ERR318658.1.fastq ../ERR318658.2.fastq ERR318658.1_kneaddata.trimmed.1.fastq ERR318658.1_kneaddata.trimmed.single.1.fastq ERR318658.1_kneaddata.trimmed.2.fastq ERR318658.1_kneaddata.trimmed.single.2.fastq
```

Error:

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Too small initial heap
```

Comment: It works when I remove the parameter "-Xmx500"

Answer (score 4):

As stated in this response :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374455/what-does-java-option-xmx-stand-for/5374501#5374501

> This value must a multiple of 1024 greater than 2MB.

and

> Append the letter k or K to indicate kilobytes, or m or M to indicate megabytes.

So you should get better results with `-Xmx500m` because `-Xmx500` means you launch the JVM with max memory of 500 bytes, which is far too small AND not a multiple of 1024 !